# Tensor Flow MNIST Evaluating predictions

Tags: tensorflow, mnist

I am working on this [tutorial](https://pythonprogramming.net/tensorflow-neural-network-session-machine-learning-tutorial/?completed=/tensorflow-deep-neural-network-machine-learning-tutorial/) and I found in this following code: when evaluating predictions he runs accuracy which runs the correct variable which in turn runs prediction which will reintialize again the weights with randoms and reconstruct the NN model. How is this right? What am I missing ?

```py
def neural_network_model(data):
    hidden_1_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([784, n_nodes_hl1])),
                      'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1]))}

    hidden_2_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1, n_nodes_hl2])),
                      'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2]))}

    hidden_3_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2, n_nodes_hl3])),
                      'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl3]))}

    output_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl3, n_classes])),
                    'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes])),}


    l1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data,hidden_1_layer['weights']), hidden_1_layer['biases'])
    l1 = tf.nn.relu(l1)

    l2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l1,hidden_2_layer['weights']), hidden_2_layer['biases'])
    l2 = tf.nn.relu(l2)

    l3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l2,hidden_3_layer['weights']), hidden_3_layer['biases'])
    l3 = tf.nn.relu(l3)

    output = tf.matmul(l3,output_layer['weights']) + output_layer['biases']

    return output

def train_neural_network(x):
    prediction = neural_network_model(x)
    cost = tf.reduce_mean( tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(prediction,y) )
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(cost)

    hm_epochs = 10
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        for epoch in range(hm_epochs):
            epoch_loss = 0
            for _ in range(int(mnist.train.num_examples/batch_size)):
                epoch_x, epoch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
                _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: epoch_x, y: epoch_y})
                epoch_loss += c
            print('Epoch', epoch, 'completed out of',hm_epochs,'loss:',epoch_loss)

        correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))

        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, 'float'))
        print('Accuracy:',accuracy.eval({x:mnist.test.images, y:mnist.test.labels}))

train_neural_network(x)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost got it right. The `accuracy` tensor indirectly depends on the `prediction` tensor, which is depending on a Tensor `x`. In your code snippet you did not include what `x` actually is; however from the linked tutorial:

```py
x = tf.placeholder('float', [None, 784])
y = tf.placeholder('float')
```

So `x` is a placeholder, i.e. a Tensor that obtains its value directly from the user. It is not entirely clear from the last line of

```py
train_neural_network(x)
```

that he is not actually calling a transformation function `train_neural_network(x)` that takes an `x` and processes it on the fly, like you would expect from a regular function; rather, the function uses a reference to the previously defined placeholder variables - dummies, really - in order to define a computation graph it then directly executes using a session. 
The graph, however, is only constructed once using `neural_network_model(x)` and then *queried* for a given number of epochs.

What you missed is this:

```py
_, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: epoch_x, y: epoch_y})
```

This queries the result of the `optimizer` operation and the `cost` tensor given that the input values are `epoch_x` for `x` and `epoch_y` for `y`, pulling data through all defined computation nodes, all the way back "down" to `x`. In order to obtain the `cost`, `y` is needed as well. Both are provided by the caller. The `AdamOptimizer` will update all trainable variables as part of its execution, changing the network's weights.

After that,

```py
accuracy.eval({x: mnist.test.images, y: mnist.test.labels})
```

or, equivalently

```py
sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y: mnist.test.labels})
```

then issues another evaluation of the *same* graph - without changing it - but this time using the inputs `mnist.test.images` for `x` and `mnist.test.labels` for `y`. 
It works because `prediction` itself depends on `x`, which is overridden to the user-provided values on each call to `sess.run(...)`.

Here is what the graph looks like in TensorBoard. It's hard to tell, but the two placeholder nodes are on the bottom left, next to the orange node called "Variable" and in the center right, below the green "Slice_1".

Here's how the relevant part of the network's graph looks like; I exported this using TensorBoard. It's a bit hard to get since the nodes are not manually labeled (except for a couple I labeled myself), but there are six relevant points here. Placeholders are yellow: On the bottom right you'll find `x` and `y` is on the center left. 
Green are the intermediate values that make sense to us: On the left is the `prediction` tensor, on the right there's the tensor called `correct`. The blue parts are endpoints of the graph: On the top left there's the `cost` tensor and on the top right you'll find `accuracy`. In essence, data flows from the bottom to the top.

[image: Network graph]

So, whenever you say "evaluate `prediction` given `x`", "evaluate `accuracy` given `x` and `y`" or "optimize my network given `x` and `y`", you really just provide values on the yellow ends and observe the outcome on the green or blue ones.

Comment: i think i didn't get it , u said that another evaluation of the same graph ,, how without changing it while prediction call neural network model  again which must be called once as it reconstruct the graph , as i kow  the calculation line which must be called only , is that what u mean ?

Comment: I know he change X as it is input , but he also change hidden layers weights and randomize it again , is that what he realy did ?

Comment: Think of it like this: The network graph is defined by `neural_network_model(x)`. That function returns a reference to a tensor `prediction` that somehow is dependent on `x`; it's not doing anything, apart from _defining_ how the network looks like. As soon as you evaluate a tensor using `sess.run()` (or `.evaluate`), that graph gets instantiated, fixed, on CPU or GPU. After that, essentially the only one changing anything is the Optimizer, `AdamOptimizer` in this case. Everything else is just fetching results of what the network produces _if_ you feed it `x` and `y`. Does that help?

Comment: The hidden layer's weights and biases are defined in the tutorial via `tf.Variable`. Variables - in contrast to placeholders and constants - are implicitly marked as "trainable", that is, they will be adjusted automatically whenever the `.minimize()` operation of an optimizer is called.

Comment: okey , but when he call the construction network  again which have the hidden layers lines this not woll randomize them again ? u mean the optmizer only which can change them after graph construction whatever he call this function or not ?

Comment: He doesn't call it again. :) It's symbolic, whenever you change `x`, the value of `prediction` changes (when you run `sess.run(prediction, feed_dict={x: ...})` on it). It's a black box, really, and you've been given the locations of the input ("`x`") and the output ("`prediction`"). `sess.run()` just drives the machinery that moves whatever you tell `x` to be through the network so that `prediction` can become whatever it is defined as.